# It does not work the field of basic entity. CRM 2013

Tags: dynamic, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Faced with the problem . There is a custom entity form which contains the essence of the field of Opportunity. When trying to change the value of this field is left blank . What could be the problem?

[Field in entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKZe0.png)

[Add Opportunity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W97fq.png)

As a result, the field remains empty.

Comment: Assume the topic for opportunity is having data or information. That is the Name property for an opportunity as lookup. 

NB: I am not well versed with your language, I assume the second column is the Topic.

Comment: On first (screenshot) page (my custom entity) red ellipse it is field of Opportunity.
On second screenshot we see searching Opportunity. After select object, field remains empty value, like on first screenshot.